# LibreOffice Icons have disappeared

Tags: gnome, libreoffice, 17.04

My icons in LibreOffice 5.3 have disappeared. How can I restore them? I am running Ubuntu 17.04 with Cinnamon, although this problem occurs also when I use unity. 
[image: Screenshot of issue]